# How to load a form action page as a new page?

Tags: html, forms, iframe

I am having a form inside a frame, when I submit it, it loads the action page inside that frame. Is there any way to load that action page as a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form target="_blank">` (assuming that when you say "page" you mean "window/tab").

Use `_top` to break out of all frames in the current window/tab.

Comment: it opens a new window. i want to load the page in the same window

Comment: @quentin he means reload the full page and not just the frame.